# How do I navigate to the start or end of a file in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, keyboard-shortcuts, hotkeys

In TextMate, for example, I use <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>uparrow</kbd> for the start of the file and <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>downarrow</kbd> for the end of the file.

Android Studio doesn't do this. How do I do the same thing in Android Studio?

Thanks.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

Cant you just use <kbd>cmd</kbd> (or <kbd>ctrl</kbd>) + <kbd>Home</kbd> / <kbd>End</kbd>

On a Mac slim keyboard (without dedicated <kbd>Home</kbd> or <kbd>End</kbd> keys), <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>Left</kbd>/<kbd>Right</kbd> arrow is the equivalent.

**So <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>Left</kbd>/<kbd>Right</kbd> arrow should go to Start/End of file.**

Comment: I have a "narrow" Apple keyboard so I don't have those keys.

Comment: Can you use something like fn + left/right arrow to simulate home/end - therefore something like cmd + fn + left arrow for beginning of file

Comment: Boom! That's it. Can you update your answer so I can select it.

Comment: To disable `fn` showing the desktop (MacOS Sierra) see this answer. https://superuser.com/questions/455603/fn-key-shows-the-desktop-on-my-mac

Comment: There so many shortcuts on android studio/intellij so I misshit something and something else happens and I don't know how to undo. But when I need a standard command, it doesn't have. Sure it is based on java, that is capable running on all platform, but not in the way it should.

Comment: I ended up changing the key bindings. Using cmd+fn+left/right is already incomfortable, but adding shift to it (to select all the text) is just too much.

Answer (score 9):

Navigate by braces, with a couple iterations you will get to `start` and `end` of file:

**To navigate to start use:**

```
command + option + [
```

**and for end use:**

```
command + option + ]
```

Once you are at the outer-most brace, you will not need multiple keystrokes.

This is especially useful for more than one closure in your java file.

[Navigating to Braces](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/navigating-to-braces.html)

Answer (score 6):

Another option (Mac): cmd-A then left arrow. This does a Select All, then moves the cursor to the start of the selection, i.e. the start of the file. I find that easy to remember.

Comment: absolutely brilliant!

Comment: excellent. I am a very smart guy (I think) but I couldn't found this solution

Answer (score 1):

For all the **Linux** users,

**Navigate to start of the file:** <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Home</kbd>

**Navigate to end of the file:** <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>End</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

For those that want to use the <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>↑</kbd>/<kbd>↓</kbd> shortcuts and change the Keymap.

Go to Preferences (<kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd>) > Keymap.

Search for `Move Caret to Text Start` and `Move Caret to Text End` and change the keyboard shortcut to (<kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>↑</kbd>) and (<kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>↓</kbd>) respectively.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me on Windows:

Navigate to start of file: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Home</kbd>

Navigate to end of file: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>End</kbd>

Simply!

---

- If your keyboard doesn't have the Home and End keys, you must do this:

  Navigate to start of file: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>Left</kbd>

  Navigate to end of file: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>Right</kbd>
- You can also do the following using Numpad, when Num Lock is turned off:

  Navigate to start of file: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>7</kbd>

  Navigate to end of file: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd>